# No able to give control to user using docusign IN PERSON feature

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi

I am using IN PERSON feature. I am using docusign for  salesforce.

When I select user as **Host in person - sign now** recipient type and select other user as signer and send the envelop.

Then email is sent to me and all the user which I have selected. When I open my email review document. I can add only my signature not the other user that I have added.

Any idea?

Comment: Are you trying this from the web browser or via an API?

Comment: I am trying from web browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the [guide for in-person signing with DocuSign for Salesforce](https://support.docusign.com/guides/dfs-user-guide-in-person-signing-dfs). If it doesn't help then please contact the support group for DocuSign.

StackOverflow is aimed at developers using the API. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks Larry. I have already implemented same as described in documentation. Yes I contact support team. Hope they will solve this issue.